# uncommenting text with sed is not working

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to uncomment a 4 line section in an (nginx config) file. Using  `sed`. I first tried with grep and the regexp seems to be correct:

```
$ grep ^#.*bny /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
#        location /bny {
```

However when I try with sed to delete the `#` at the start of the line it fails:

```
$ sudo sed -i '/^#.*bny/,+3 s/^#+//' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
$ grep ^#.*bny /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
#        location /bny {
```

I think I use the same tactics for commenting the section with sed and that works just fine:

```
sudo sed -i '/bny/,+3 s/^/#/' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Even double commenting is no problem. What am I doing wrong with the uncommenting?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is literal in basic regular expression (BRE) syntax, so your substitution pattern fails to match.

You can use `s/^##*//`, `s/^#\{1,\}//` or (in GNU sed) `s/^#\+//`, or switch to extended regular expressions (ERE) using the `-E` or `-r` command line option.